# Hide character with jQuery inside a span with a class

Tags: html, jquery, woocommerce

I've looked for the solution to this but nothing seems to be working.

I have an SKU within a span with a class of "sku". Some of the SKUs have periods before the SKU to allow for adding more than one product with the same SKU.

I'd like to hide the periods when the SKU is displayed though.

This is my code:

`<span class="sku">..THESKU</span>`

And this is the jQuery I am using:

```
<script>
    $('span.sku').html($('span.sku').html().replace('.',''));
</script>
```

Is the right, or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: You have to put another tag around the text you want to style, specifically.

Comment: Also the reuse of the same selector is a code smell, if multiple elements on the page can match it.  As you will be setting all of the elements to the same value.  The use of a contextual selector, or an `each()` would make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only replace one `dot '.'`. You can use regex to remove all the dots instead:

```
const skus = $('span.sku');

$('span.sku').each(function() {
  const text = $(this).html();
  const cleaned = text.replace(/\./g,'');
  $(this).html(cleaned);
})
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Updated as suggested by @Taplar

Comment: Thank you for this. It still doesn't seem to work though. I have the jQuery in the footer of the page - does it need to go before the SKU is displayed? Thanks.

Comment: @Emma Your script needs to run after your SKU values are displayed. Is there no event handlers available for you to include the script?

Comment: @Taplar I understand what you are saying now. Let me update that then.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I've tried that but it still doesn't work. I'm using a wordpress theme and it does include jQuery (I've used jQuery for other parts of the site). Is that was you mean by event handlers? (Sorry, jQuery isn't my strong point). The script is in the footer so it is after the SKU is displayed, but does it need to be straight after? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I see now. Wordpress isn't my sweet spot, but you can try temporary testing with a `setTimeout(...)` and the script above. I feel like we are missing something here. 

If your page is loading your data through an API, that could be the reason you are encountering some race issue.

Comment: Thanks for that. I added a setTimeout and it didn't work either. It's strange though as I have other javascript before this that works fine. The SKUs are from the product information in WooCommerce, so I'm not sure about the API.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to give an update with this. I still couldn't get the periods to hide, but I found a way to have duplicate SKUs so there was no longer a need for this. Thanks for all your help.

If anyone has a similar issue, the code I used is below which I added to the themes functions file.

`add_filter( 'wc_product_has_unique_sku', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX );`